# Проблема с подсчетом страниц в Label используя pageControl

Tags: ios, swift, label, page

Столкнулся с проблемой отображения текущей страницы в лейбле при использовании **pageControl**.
**pageControl** использую вместе с **scrollView**. Отображение страниц происходит в лейбле. Когда листаю страницу вперед подсчет страницы становится на **+ 1**, но когда листаю назад ничего не происходит, происходит только тогда когда я два раза листаю назад.

Вот код:

```
class ScrollImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollImage: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPagesLabel: UILabel!

    private var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imagesArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imagesArray.count

        self.numberOfPagesLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.numberOfPagesLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"

        for i in 0..<imagesArray.count {

            imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagesArray[i]))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollImage.frame.width, height: self.scrollImage.frame.height)

            scrollImage.contentSize.width = scrollImage.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            scrollImage.addSubview(imageView)

        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let currentPage = scrollImage.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        if pageControl.currentPage < imagesArray.count {
            self.pageControl.currentPage += 1
            self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage + 1)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"
        } else if pageControl.currentPage != 0 {
            self.pageControl.currentPage -= 1
            self.numberOfPagesLabel.text = "\(self.pageControl.currentPage - 1)/\(self.imagesArray.count)"
        }    
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
    }
}
```

И гифка чтобы было понятнее как все происходит.

[image: гифка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в округлении

```
let currentPage = scrollImage.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
```

Попробуйте этот метод в делегате

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
numberOfPagesLabel?.text = String(Int(pageNumber))
}
```

Единственная разница `pageControl` Перемещается только окончания прокрутки скрола

Comment: Не помогло, если оставить часть код в didScrollView и перенести другую часть которые вы предложили в DidEnd то страницы в лейбле пролистываются до конца и там и остаются, но перемещение страниц происходит только в pageContol, в лейбле постоянно стоит 23/23 (например).
А если перенести весь код из didScroll в DidEnd то картина та же самая получается что и в изначальном вопросе

Comment: Попробуйте удалить scrollViewDidScroll, а в метод который я предложил добавить numberOfPagesLabel?.text = String(Int(pageNumber))

Comment: Получилось, спасибо большое) Исправите ответ с добавлением строки кода?